# "apt" module stops in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

I'm learning Ansible and I'm having a problem with the "apt" module. 
I wrote the ansible.cfg and the inventory files and I can correctly run

```
ansible testserver -m ping
```

Now I'm trying to install NGinx on the target, running

```
ansible testserver -s -m apt -a name=nginx
```

but the operation stops. This is the output with the "-vvv" flag

```
<IP> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: user
<IP> REMOTE_MODULE apt name=nginx
<IP> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', 'IP', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986'"]
<IP> PUT /tmp/tmpWaB4Lf TO /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986/apt
<IP> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', 'IP', '/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=gakusrfbokzukkfpfgbvuseekjyqlllu] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-gakusrfbokzukkfpfgbvuseekjyqlllu; /usr/bin/python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986/apt; rm -rf /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445515245.75-119301060889986/ >/dev/null 2>&1\'"\'"\'\'']
```

Do you have any idea what about the origin of the problem?

Thank you

Comment: is `aptitude` installed on the remote server ? the `apt` module needs it behind the scenes... could be an idea.

Comment: Yes. I think I found the solution: it seems that the sudo command must not require the password for everything to work correctly. 
This means that I had to configure a passwordless sudo (http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password)

Answer (score 2):

I notice you concluded the problem was with sudo.  Just to let you know, you don't *have* to have passwordless sudo enabled on the machine you are targeting.  You can use the `--ask-sudo-pass` flag when running your Ansible playbook.